# Access-Control-Allow-Origin chrome extension persmission not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cors

I try to get the html page from a internal webserver in my js code, and parse it to make bookmarks.

At the moment I have problems with Access-Control-Allow-Origin, but the permissions are set !

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "options_page":"config.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "test.html",
      "permissions": [
   "*://*/*"
  ],
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://example.com; object-src 'self'"
      }
}
```

I try the code from the example here : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.example.com/data.json", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    // JSON.parse does not evaluate the attacker's scripts.
    var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  }
}
xhr.send();
```

But I get the error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.example.com/data.json. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://nnbpdlokhkemfjmfkmlfnjonmeaccdmo'
>   is therefore not allowed access.

I'm pretty lost !

Actually I want to do that (that doesn't work either) :

```
function httpGet(url,user,pass)
{
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET",url, false );
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(user + ":" +pass))
    xmlHttp.send( null );
   response= xmlHttp.responseText;
   startT=response.indexOf("menuData = [");
//alert(startT);
   Text=response.substr(startT+11 );
   Text=Text.substr(0,Text.indexOf("\n"));
   var obj = eval (Text)
   return Text
}
```

Comment: The `permissions` section of the manifest should be an independent entry, not located inside `browser_action`

Comment: Many thanks, I was searching and searching.... ! would you want to post it as answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `permissions` section of the manifest should be an independent entry, not located inside `browser_action`. Check the documentation for the [manifest file format](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest).